# Set meta ogg image from django-cms plugin context

Tags: python, django, meta-tags, django-cms, ogg

My problem:

I need to set an ogg image from a carousel plugin which is present on all pages of a django-cms site. My base template where the `<head>` tag resides is the parent template of the django cms base.

Simply adding a `{% block meta_image %}` to my base template and populate it from the cms plugin template wont do it. Is there any way I can access the global context from a plugins render method?

Comment: Have you tried using sekizai to add the meta tag to the block on the parent template?

Comment: You mr @Brandon sir are fantastic. Sekizai worked like a charm, I'll have to look into that in more detail why it is so. Meanwhile post this as an answer and I'll make sure to mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to leverage [django-sekizai](https://django-sekizai.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which is already a dependency of Django-CMS to add the meta tag to any block on the parent in a non-duplicative manner:

```
# base-template.html

{% load sekizai_tags %}

{% block meta %}
    {# some default content might be here #}
{% endblock meta %}
{% render_block "meta" %}


# your-plugin-template.html

{% load sekizai_tags %}

{% block meta %}
    {% addtoblock "meta" %}
        <meta property="og:image" content="{{ instance.value }}" />
    {% endaddtoblock %}
{% endblock meta %}
```